# Find the number of pairs (A[i], A[j]) such that i < j and A[i]**A[j] > A[j]**A[i]

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I have written the following code for the following problem:

Given a  sequence A of N positive integers, write a program to find the number of pairs (A[i], A[j]) such that i < j and A[i]<sup>A[j]</sup> > A[j]<sup>A[i]</sup> (A[i] raised to the power A[j] > A[j] raised to the power A[i]).

My code is passing all the test cases except this one:

```
15 
0 5 2 3 0 8 7 8 0 7 1 2 4 5 3
```

Output should be 35, but my program is giving output 0.
My program is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int power(int x, int y);

int main()
{
int N,A[N],count=0;
scanf("%d",&N);
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&A[i]);
}
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++)
    {
        if(i<j)
        {
        if(power(A[i],A[j])>power(A[j],A[i]))
            count++;
        }
    }
}
printf("%d",count);

return 0;
}


int power(int x, int y)
{
    int result = x;

    if(y == 0) return 1;
    if(x < 0 || y < 0) return 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < y; ++i)
        result *= x;

    return result;
}
```

Please suggest the correction(s) in the code in C language only.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use the formatting tools that the site offers when asking a question. Besides the bug that Gassa addresses in his answer you also should consider to use a different type than `int`. With `int`, powers overflow easily. My guess would be that your prof meant you to use `double` and then use the existing library function `pow` for the power.

Comment: I was not allowed to use library functions while making this program so I had to define power function myself.

Regarding formatting tools,I am new and yes I am learning to use them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change your code into:

```
int main()
{
   int N,count=0,i,j;
   scanf("%d",&N);
   int A[N];
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaration

```
int N,A[N],count=0;
```

does not make sense. On this line, you don't know the value of `N` when you allocate the array `A`. Try allocating space for `A` *after* you know the value of `N`.